# GROUP_CONCAT sort based on secondary table

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to sort `GROUP_CONCAT` based on a secondary table?

I have 3 tables setup similar to:

```
users          usersPrivilegeGroups     privilegeGroupsPriority
-----------    ---------------------    -----------------------
userid PK      groupName FK             groupName PK
username       userid FK                priority int
               active
```

Using the following I retrieve the matching users' data with related `usersPrivilegeGroups.groupName` concat'ed into a single field:

```sql
SELECT
    users.*,
    GROUP_CONCAT(privList.groupName separator ',') AS privilegeGroups
FROM users
    LEFT JOIN usersPrivilegeGroups privList
    ON (privList.userid = users.userid AND privList.active = 1)
WHERE users.userid = ...
```

Is there a way to sort the matched groups(`privGroups`) based on the `privilegeGroupsPriority.priority` in ascending order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `JOIN` priority table and perform an `ORDER BY` the priority value inside `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT
    users.*,
    GROUP_CONCAT(privList.groupName separator ',' 
                 ORDER BY priority.priority ) AS privilegeGroups
FROM users

    LEFT JOIN usersPrivilegeGroups privList
    ON (privList.userid = users.userid AND privList.active = 1)

    LEFT JOIN privilegeGroupsPriority priority
    ON privList.groupName = priority.groupName

WHERE users.userid = ...
```